# animate images in sequence

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an array of 24 high quality images. I am trying to animate them using uiimageView.animationImages property. But the app is crashing whenever I try to run this animation. I have searched a lot on this and found that the crashing is due to the number of high resolution images I am trying to animate. But I am not able find any alternative for this. I tried using animated gif images but the quality is too bad. Please help.

Comment: can you put code or error?

Comment: self.imageView.animationImages = myImages;
self.imageView.animationDuration = 2.0;
[self.imageView startAnimating];                                                    This is the code I am using for animation. There is no erro r.. The app is crashing because imageView.animationImages is eating up all the device memory. I want an efficient alternative of this method.

Comment: can you also provide what error you getting ....may be code is work good ?

Comment: try using instrumental tool which might specify you the reason of causing memory leak, else the only option stays is optimising image

Comment: You can also try to achieve the same animation effect using CAKeyFrameAnimation if you are comfortable with.

Comment: May be these will help you:-
1)Tried to add placeholder image.
2)Tried to set animation in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create your own `UIImageView` class with an `NSArray` of all images. Load all `UIImages`, start a `NSTimer` and cycle through all `UIImages`. This might not be the most efficient way but it shouldn't crash.

Comment: No, this will crash also.

Answer (score 0):

Although the images are high resolution and big, your screen size is small. So I would say scale down the images to you max screen size and then try using animationImage property of UIImageView.

That way you save on memory and load time.